# Вектор умных указателей на структуру

Tags: c++, smart-pointer

Изучаю умные указатели и не могу понять, почему не правильный вывод, выводит последние введенные данные. Как правильно помещать в вектор умные указатели?

```
Входные данные:
Title: Insight
Rating: 78
Price: 60

Title: Moon
Rating: 50
Price: 30

Выходные данные:
Title: Moon
Rating: 50
Price: 30
Title: Moon
Rating: 50
Price: 30



struct Review {
        std::string title = "";
        int rating = 0;
        double price = 0.00;
    };
    bool FillReview(std::shared_ptr<Review> &rr);
    void ShowReview(const std::shared_ptr<Review> &rr);
    
    int main() {
       using namespace std;
       vector<shared_ptr<Review>> books;
       shared_ptr<Review> temp = make_shared<Review>();
       while (FillReview(temp)) {
           books.push_back(temp);
           if (books.size() > 0) {
               cout << "Thank you. You entered the following " << books.size() << endl;
               cout << "Rating\tBook\tPrice" << endl;
               for_each(books.begin(), books.end(), ShowReview);
           }
           else {
               cout << "No entries.";
           }
       }
        cout << "Bye.\n";
        return 0;
    }
    
    bool FillReview(std::shared_ptr<Review>& rr){
        std::cout << "Enter book title (quit to quit): ";
        std::getline(std::cin, rr->title);
        if (rr->title == "quit") {
            return false;
        }
        std::cout << "Enter book rating: ";
        std::cin >> rr->rating;
        if (!std::cin) {
    
            return false;
        }
        std::cout << "Enter book price: ";
        std::cin >> rr->price;
        while (std::cin.get() != '\n') {
            continue;
        }
        return true;
    }
    
    void ShowReview(const std::shared_ptr<Review> &rr) {
            std::cout << rr->rating << "\t" << rr->title << "\t" << rr->price << std::endl;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы создаете указатель один раз, и потом меняете данные по этому указателю и добавляете копию одного и того же указателя в вектор. Если вы хорошо знакомы с обычными глупыми указателями, представьте, что у вас `temp` это обычный указатель, а `make_shared` эквивалентно `new`. После этого поведение программы должно стать очевидным.

Вам надо выделять память для каждого объекта отдельно, самый простой (не не самый изящный с точки зрения дизайна кмк) вариант это перенести вызов `make_shared` в начало функции `FillReview`, тогда под каждый новый объект будет выделяться своя область памяти.

Comment: И вправду, что-то я забыл, что они по сути являются такими же указателями. Дополню ваш ответ, нужно в конце добавить вызов `std::move(temp)` иначе на выходе будем получать нули и пустые строки.